# SSRS 2008 Matrix - Column Data Incorrect

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to convert an old local Crystal Report.  Basically, for a given order, there are multiple line items.  The report needs to show Order and Vendor in the left two columns, then a variable number of columns (that fit on a page) to display the line numbers.

To do this, I added a Matrix, and adding the groupings and all that.  However, I get only one line item for each Order/Vendor combination, even though each combination has at least two line items.

Current:

```
============================================
+ Order     + Vendor      + Item 1 + Item 2 ...
============================================
+ OrdValue1 + VendValue1  + Value  + [blank]
============================================
+ OrdValue2 + VendValue2  + [blank]+ Value
============================================
```

Desired:

```
============================================
+ Order     + Vendor      + Item 1 + Item 2 ...
============================================
+ OrdValue1 + VendValue1  + Value  + Value
============================================
+ OrdValue2 + VendValue2  + Value  + Value
============================================
```

Edit:
[image: Current output]

Comment: Looks like a **grouping issue**. For **row** you need to `group` on `Order` and `Vendor`. For **column** you need to group on `Item`.

Comment: @AnupAgrawal Very close.  I now at least get all the items, whereas before I got exactly one item per order/vendor.  However, there still seems to be something wrong with my grouping, as there are lots of blanks.  Each column has one item value, with all other fields for that column being blank, as opposed to rolling up as a I would like.

Comment: Can you show with an example where you are showing blank values and rolling up you are not able to see.

Comment: @AnupAgrawal I have added what I am getting.  That should all roll up so that the first row has 318433, then 318432, then blanks.  Row 2 should have 315837 then blanks, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go back to the source Dataset (assuming it is SQL) and add a Column_Number calculation which resets to 1 for each Order + Vendor combination, e.g.

`ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( PARTITION BY Order , Vendor ORDER BY Line_Number ) AS Column_Number`

Then I would edit the Column Group defintion to use that Column_Number column.

Comment: That worked.  There was some weirdness in between that I don't understand, but the important thing is that it works.

Comment: can you please elaborate? i think im having the same problem but i do not know whats happening, my matrix gives weird data on some part of the grid.